# Showing that $e^{2\pi i /5}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Show that there are no $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $e^{2\pi i/5}=a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt{2}+d(\sqrt[4]{2})^{-1}$

Previously in this problem, I found all the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ with the help of the subgroups of $D_4$ and Galois's Theorem  as you can see in the following image:
[image]

Additionally, I have the following idea:
$e^{2\pi i /5}=a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c(\sqrt[4]{2})^2+\frac{d}{2}(\sqrt[4]{2})^3$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Therefore $e^{2\pi i /5}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$.

If I could prove that $e^{2\pi i /5}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$ I would have the request but I don't know how to use the subfields found in the image for this (or maybe it should be solved another way)

How can proves this?

Answer (score 5):

If $e^{2\pi i/5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$, then $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}) \cong D_4$ has a quotient isomorphic to $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. But you can check that $D_4$ does not have any cyclic quotients of order $4$.

Comment: but $\langle \sigma\rangle$ is cyclic of order $4$ in $D_4$ or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That's a subgroup of order $4$, not a quotient.

Comment: That is because $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i /5})/\mathbb{Q})\simeq \frac{Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}}{ Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})}$ and $|Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})|=2$ then $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})\simeq \mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: why not exists cyclic quotient  of ordeer 4 in $D_4$? I not see this

Comment: If $D_4=<x,y:x^4=y^2=xyxy=e>$
$D_4/<y>=\left\{ \left\{e,y\right\},\left\{x,xy\right\},\left\{x^2,x^2y\right\},\left\{x^3,x^3y\right\}\right\}=<x<y>>$ therefore $D_4/<y>$ is cyclic! What is wrong?.

Comment: $\left<y\right>$ is not a normal subgroup, so you can't quotient by it.